# Microsoft Graph Security Alerts. Problem with status

Tags: security, graph, alerts

I'm having problems with the 'status' field from the Microsoft Graph Security API.

example

```
GET /graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts/03da5d48-a892-4ea6-9949-dc902283e2d8f
```

Returns status 200 with a JSON object.

The problem is that the alert is **'resolved'** in Cloud App Security.
But the API returns **"status": "newAlert"** on the object.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Docs: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/alert-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

If you updated the alert status via Cloud App Security portal and then called Get method from the Graph Security API, you should see that the alert status returned from the API reflected as such. If you don't see the status update as expected, then please file a Github issue with details of your issue [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/security-api-solutions).